# Difference between list and map for getting multiple user inputs

Tags: python

What is the difference between `list(int(input()).split())` and `map(int,input().split())` for getting multiple inputs from user?

Comment: Did you even try the first one?

Comment: there is big difference - first gives error message, second works without error. OR maybe you mean `list(int(x) for x in input().split())` ?

Comment: Second one produces a `map` object in Python 3, which is fine. You might need to wrap a `list()` to make it a list.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine them closely:

`list(int(input()).split())` expands into

```
list(           # Make a list out of...
    int(        # the value of... 
        input() # input from the user,
    )           # converted to an integer.
    .split()    # Then, split that.
)
```

This doesn't make sense. Say you input something like `15`. The `input()` function returns the string `'15'`, which gets converted into the integer `15`. Integers don't have a `.split()` operation, so you get a `SyntaxError`.

Now, let's look at `map(int,input().split())`:

```
map(             # Apply the function...
    int          # (that is, `int()`)
    ,            # ...to every element in the iterable...
    input()      # (First, take the input from the user,
        .split() # and then split it)
)                # ...and return all that as a list
```

This time, we input something like `1 5 6 11 13`.

1. The `input()` function returns the string `'1 5 6 11 13'`.
2. Then, we call the `.split()` function on that string, which returns a list of substrings that were separated by whitespace - that is, it returns the list `['1', '5', '6', '11', '13']`. These are still strings, though, and we want integers.
3. Finally, we apply `int()` to every element of that list, which gets us the end result `[1, 5, 6, 11, 13]`, except it's in a `map` data structure (which is more efficient for python to create in this case than a full list)
4. If we want, we could cast that to a `list` to use it easily - that would just be enclosing that entire expression in `list(...)`.